# After create site collection with powershell UI is broken

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, site-template, spsite

After creating a site collection with PowerShell UI is broken.

**My PowerShell code is**

```
New-SPSite -Url $SiteColl_URL -OwnerAlias $SiteColl_Owner -Language 1033 -Template "CMSPUBLISHING#0" -Name $SiteColl_Name
```

P.S: (Template is: `CMSPUBLISHING#0`)

**Result is:**

[image]

SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure is activated

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have enabled SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure below Site Collection Administration>  Site collection features

Comment: Can i do this through PowerShell?

Comment: Try this *Enable-SPFeature -Identity "PublishingSite" -url "your site"*

Comment: Enable-SPFeature : Feature 'PublishingSite' (ID: f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa) is already activated at scope

Comment: Wild guess if this is happening only in IE then add it in "Trusted Sites" and try. if the error still persists then open developer tools in IE then change the document type to 'Edge' (i.e. 10 to edge) and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2010? I tested the same script but it works fine in my 2010 environment. Could you check if the issue is caused by browser compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

**First,** The template ID  `CMSPUBLISHING#0` should be used with subsites that its site collection has `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` enabled.

**Secondly,** to enable `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure`

- Open site collection > Site Setting > Site Collection Administration > Site collection features

[image]

- Activate `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure`

[image]

---

To enable `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` using PowerShell

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity "PublishingSite" -url "your site"
```

Comment: I have this resualt after execute a command: Enable-SPFeature : Feature 'PublishingSite' (ID: f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa) is already activated at scope

Comment: do you face this issue with other templates?!

Comment: I did not try, but business logic requires the site collection to have a publication template.

Comment: Try to go to the site features of the current site and make sure  
SharePoint Server Publishing is activated

Comment: See my updated question

Comment: Okay great this *SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure* is already enabled, what about this *SharePoint Server Publishing* in the current site not site collection!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70939/discussion-between-goshky-and-m-qassas).